# What use is the --state option of iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I just don't get the `--state` option of `iptables`.

I have read the example about NEW,ESTABLISHED and RELATED. But why is this required?

I mean, when I open a port e.g. 22. The communication is via 22 and that's it. Why should I use this state parameter?

Maybe Port 22 is a bad example. But is the state just for opening more ports when I created an ACCEPTED NEW have an ESTABLISHED or RELATED connection?

For example: whats the difference between:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 22 -m state -j ACCEPT
```

Both should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 22 -m state -j ACCEPT
```

This would allow any TCP connection with source port 22 from anywhere to any port on your machine, not just return packets of an outgoing SSH connection. If you're running any server on the machine, in any port, not just SSH, anyone can connect to it if they happen to guess to use 22 as the source port. Security by obscurity.

Conntrack tracks the outgoing connections that were actually opened from your system instead, so tell `iptables` to accept incoming packets of `ESTABLISHED`
connections, you know you get those and only those.

Though note that something like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

would only allow replies to outgoing SSH connections (to port 22). You'd need to replicate that for all other ports anything on the system needs to connect to, mirroring any rules in the `OUTPUT` chain.

Another example might be something like this to accept packets to high ports, to allow reply packets to (any) outgoing connections:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
```

This would also allow any connections to any servers running on the high ports (e.g. 8080 or 6667), even ones that are accidentally left running. Of course you could limit that range more, but then you'd need to verify what range your system uses for outgoing connections.

Then again, with TCP, you could add `! --syn` to prevent new connections, but with UDP that's not possible as return or reply packets are no different from initial packets on the low level. There, conntrack is pretty much the only option to tell apart connections just recently opened from the system, from other packets that just happen to come from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "Both should work", it means both do what **you** want them do, but **we** don't know what you want.

The first pair of rules will allow **outgoing** connections to a remote port 22. This may or may not be what you intend. Most people are more concerned with limiting incoming connections.

The second pair of rules also allows outgoing connections to a remote port 22. But with firewalls, it is easy to test that what should be allowed is actually allowed. It's more difficult to test that what should be blocked is really blocked.

In this case, the second pair of rules will allow incoming connections to any port, as long as the remote port is 22. I'm sure that is not what you intend. In the past, I've seen many attempts to connect with source port 22 precisely because of such rules on stateless firewalls. I didn't look recently, such attempts may still be common, it is easy for an attacker to select the source port.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

will **not** allow any new connections.

From the man page: *"NEW  meaning that  the packet has started a new connection, or otherwise associated with a connection which has not seen packets in both directions"*. IOW, this rule alone, when the default policy is to DROP/REJECT will not allow you to connect to the host.

Comment: So if I remove the `-m state` option, the default policy from `iptables -P OUTPUT DROP` will block any incoming port 22 ?

Comment: Your rules, the way you write them and think about them are fragmented and ineffective. If you need, I can pen you the most basic IPv4 iptables rules which would be a ton easier to understand and manage. *I remove the -m state option, the default policy from iptables -P OUTPUT DROP will block any incoming port 22* without seeing the rest of the rules it's impossible to say.